# How to make testing an SQL Query faster?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was given this code for a SQL query, but for the life of me can't figure out what exactly is going on.  I'm pretty new to SQL so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM ( SELECT rownum as rn
                 , a.* 
            FROM ( SELECT outbound.MSG_ID
                        , outbound.MSG_TYPE
                        , outbound.FROM_ADDR
                        , outbound.TO_ADDR
                        , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
                        , outbound.CREATION_DATE
                        , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID     
                     FROM MESSAGES outbound 
                    WHERE (1 = 1)
                   GROUP BY outbound.MSG_ID
                          , outbound.MSG_TYPE
                          , outbound.FROM_ADDR
                          , outbound.TO_ADDR
                          , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
                          , outbound.CREATION_DATE
                          , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID 
                   ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC ) a 
        ) 
   WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 25
```

I'm specifically having touble understanding `SELECT rownum as rn, a.* FROM (`...`a )` but I assume this is where I would edit the query to only check 1000 rows (which is my goal).  Right now it's checking all entries in the database (750,000) and I only want it to check 1000 for testing.

Thanks!

Comment: First step - re-format the query to make it easier to follow!

Comment: rn is here to get a row number. The `where rn between 1 and 25` is here to take only 25 first rows (by highest creation_date). If you want the 1000 first, change 25... to 1000

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus that's what I figured, right now it's split up so only 25 results are displayed at once.  However, I'm wondering if there's a way I could only search 1000 database entries instead of the 750000 to speed up the search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, let's start picking this guy apart. Starting with the subquery

```
SELECT outbound.MSG_ID
                        , outbound.MSG_TYPE
                        , outbound.FROM_ADDR
                        , outbound.TO_ADDR
                        , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
                        , outbound.CREATION_DATE
                        , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID     
                     FROM MESSAGES outbound 
                    WHERE (1 = 1)
                   GROUP BY outbound.MSG_ID
                          , outbound.MSG_TYPE
                          , outbound.FROM_ADDR
                          , outbound.TO_ADDR
                          , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
                          , outbound.CREATION_DATE
                          , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID 
                   ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC
```

What's happening there is the subquery is selecting msg_id, msg_type, etc from the table MESSAGES. It's aliasing that table and calling it outbound. FROM MESSAGES outbound means "get the data from MESSAGES but call the table outbound instead."

Now, you might note the WHERE (1=1) clause... that's trivially true, and will always occur. Sometimes people use WHERE (1=1) because a script somewhere adds additional filters if certain parameters are selected. For now don't worry about that.

Last, the GROUP BY {blah blah blah} is telling your database to dedup these data. It's effectively SELECT DISTINCT. Last, the subquery is ordered by Creation_date DESC so the most recent occurrence of a message is the one that is selected. If I had to guess, the deduping and ordering is because this is a messaging system that might contain essentially duplicate records (like maybe someone resent the same email) or because messaging systems are often distributed and don't emphasize consistency on write, but rather write speed. I have no idea why exactly they needed to dedup these guys, but the important thing for you is that someone thought it was necessary and they were probably right.

Outside of the subquery you see

```
SELECT rownum as rn
                 , a.*
```

Everything that the subquery was doing got labelled "a". Remember that alias concept from earlier. Your entire subquery has an alias too, and it's called "a".  So, we are selecting everything from a ("a.*") and we are also selecting the rownumber and calling that rn. The where clause at the very end says "give me the first 25 rows."

So... if you want to select 1000 rows in this manner (dedup, keep the most recent, etc) then just change WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 25 to WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 1000.

If, on the other hand, you don't want to dedup messages at all and only want the top 1000 rows of the table, then

```
    SELECT outbound.MSG_ID
                            , outbound.MSG_TYPE
                            , outbound.FROM_ADDR
                            , outbound.TO_ADDR
                            , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
                            , outbound.CREATION_DATE
                            , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID     
                         FROM MESSAGES outbound 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000;
```

should do the job.

Does this help?

Comment: this is perfect, thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for:  a clear explanation of what is happening and also an answer to how to only search 1000 entries.  Again, thank you

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question you need to determine how early do you want to limit the subset of records your query will be checking for testing.

Also, you have to define what your goal is with testing: Are you looking to do simple check to determine if the query can be executed? Or are you actually looking to prove correctness?

If you just want to test that it executes you could put a limit very early on, something like this:

```
  -- first part of query omitted for brevity
 SELECT TOP 1000 outbound.MSG_ID
      , outbound.MSG_TYPE
      , outbound.FROM_ADDR
      , outbound.TO_ADDR
      , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
      , outbound.CREATION_DATE
      , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID     
  FROM MESSAGES outbound
  -- bottom part of query omitted for brevity
```

Or, for fastest performance, limit the initial source:

```
 -- first part of query omitted for brevity
 SELECT outbound.MSG_ID
      , outbound.MSG_TYPE
      , outbound.FROM_ADDR
      , outbound.TO_ADDR
      , outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT
      , outbound.CREATION_DATE
      , outbound.MQ_MSG_ID     
  FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM MESSAGES) outbound
  -- bottom part of query omitted for brevity
```

Comment: Do I totally miss something ? I think there's no "TOP" in oracle, or ?

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for, Thank you!  Weirdly, however, TOP keeps giving me a syntax error. Edit:  syntax error is because sqlite.  Thanks!

Comment: Miky's questions above are the exact questions you should be asking here... could not agree more.